# Warning - 12200 Schema validation warning The provided XML does not conform to the Twilio Markup XML schema

Tags: http, post, twilio, twilio-twiml

I'm setting up a Twilio-Dialogflow WhatsApp Chatbot following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5EMHIQiGWE

code as below:

```
from http.client import responses
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import os, dialogflow
from flask.globals import session
from google.api_core.exceptions import InvalidArgument
import requests

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = 'private_key.json'
DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID = 'whatsapp-twilio-flask-dia-svau'
DIALOGFLOW_LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
SESSION_ID = 'me'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

@app.route('/')
def root():
    return "Hello World"

@app.route('/api/getMessage', methods=['POST'])
def home():
    message = request.form.get('Body')
    mobnum = request.form.get('From')
    session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()
    session = session_client.session_path(DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID, SESSION_ID)
    text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(text=message, language_code = DIALOGFLOW_LANGUAGE_CODE)
    query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)
    try:
        response = session_client.detect_intent(session=session, query_input=query_input)
    except InvalidArgument:
        raise
    sendMessage(mobnum,response.query_result.fulfillment_text)
    return response.query_result.fulfillment_text

def sendMessage(mobnum,message):
    url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/XXXXXXXXXX/Messages.json"
    payload = {'From': 'whatsapp:+14155238886',  'Body': message,   'To': mobnum}
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'  }
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers = headers, data=payload)
    print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
    return ""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

running the code gives this error at Twilio, because of this I'm not getting a reply in the WhatsApp

```
Warning - 12200
Schema validation warning
The provided XML does not conform to the Twilio Markup XML schema.
```

response.text returns this :

```
print(response.text.encode('utf8')) :

b'{"sid": "XXX", "date_created": "XXX", "date_updated": "XXX", "date_sent": null, "account_sid": "XXX", "to": "whatsapp:+XXX", "from": "whatsapp:+XXX", "messaging_service_sid": null, "body": "Good day! What can I do for you today?", "status": "queued", "num_segments": "1", "num_media": "0", "direction": "outbound-api", "api_version": "2010-04-01", "price": null, "price_unit": null, "error_code": null, "error_message": null, "uri": "XXX", "subresource_uris": {"media": "XXX"}}'
```

Anybody can help, please? Am I getting the above error from Twilio because I did not use twilio.twiml libraries? But from the tutorial video, I don't see this library being used.

Comment: I would like to help here, but I think I need a bit more context. The 12200 error is caused when you don't respond to an incoming webhook request from Twilio with correct TwiML, but I can't see where you are responding to a request here. Can you share the code that responds to the HTTP request from Twilio please?

Comment: Hi @philnash thank you for your reply, I have edited the code, can help to take a look again? thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The way that you (and the video tutorial) have set up the response is not quite right. You have the WhatsApp sandbox webhook pointed at your `/api/getMessage` endpoint, which is correct, but the way you respond to that request is not right for Twilio.

When Twilio makes a webhook request to your application it expects the response to be an XML response, containing [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/twiml). You can even use TwiML to respond with a message, so you don't need to make requests to the REST API to send the message.

Another thing you can do, to make things easier, is to [install and use the Twilio Python helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python). You can use it to make requests to the API and also to build TwiML responses.

So, I would recommend that you install the Twilio Python library:

```
pip install twilio
```

Then use the library in your app to build up and return a TwiML response, like this:

```py
from http.client import responses
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, Response
import os, dialogflow
from flask.globals import session
from google.api_core.exceptions import InvalidArgument
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse
import requests

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = 'private_key.json'
DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID = 'whatsapp-twilio-flask-dia-svau'
DIALOGFLOW_LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
SESSION_ID = 'me'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

@app.route('/')
def root():
    return "Hello World"

@app.route('/api/getMessage', methods=['POST'])
def home():
    message = request.form.get('Body')
    mobnum = request.form.get('From')
    session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()
    session = session_client.session_path(DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID, SESSION_ID)
    text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(text=message, language_code = DIALOGFLOW_LANGUAGE_CODE)
    query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)
    try:
        intent = session_client.detect_intent(session=session, query_input=query_input)
    except InvalidArgument:
        raise
    response = MessagingResponse()
    response.message(intent.query_result.fulfillment_text)
    return Response(str(response), mimetype="application/xml")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

In this code, instead of calling the original `sendMessage` function we import `MessagingResponse` from `twilio.twiml.messaging_response` and create  a response that we return as XML, using the `Response` object to set both the content and the mimetype.

```py
Response(str(response), mimetype="application/xml")
```

This will both simplify your code and get rid of the schema validation warning. Check this blog post on [building with Twilio and Flask](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/03/building-python-web-apps-with-flask.html) for more information.