# Twilio MessagingResponse not sending SMS inbound message

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, twiliosms

I'm currently following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=knxlmCVFAZI) from [twilio](/questions/tagged/twilio) on how to send inbound messages (starts in minute 2). I've set up a webhook to call a /sms route on my Flask app, and I'm using ngrok to make the application accessible on the Internet. When I send an SMS to my Twilio number, I can successfully print the incoming request.form, including the message SID and other details. So far, the first part of the code is functioning correctly.

However, I'm facing an issue with the code towards the end, which is supposed to instantiate a MessagingResponse to send a confirmation that the message has been received. Unfortunately, this part is not working as expected. I'm not receiving any SMS message on my phone, and when I check the SMS logs page on Twilio.com while logged into my project, I don't see any Outgoing API record for the sent message. Strangely, I can see the test message I sent to our number as an Incoming message, but the confirmation response is not going through.

This is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/sms', methods=["GET","POST"])
def sms():
    print(request.form)

    resp = MessagingResponse()
    resp.message(body="Subscribe")
    
    return str(resp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

There is no error or exception so I can't even debug. I'm not super advanced so maybe it could be something that's right in front of me.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or help in resolving this problem and making the messaging response work as intended.

Other things I've tried so far:

- Opened Inbound and Outbound windows defender firewall to port 5000. (didn't do anything)
- Tried different codes where you have to use the Client library and create environment variables for you account_sid and token as well as specify the "to" number and it works. However, this approach isn't going to work for me, I really need to get the MessagingResponse way to work because I want to store each user with their own cookies.
- I'm getting a 200 response from both Flask and ngrok.
- Tried with and without the body key.
- Do I need somoe sort of validator or environment keys for this approach or the webhook "takes care" of this?

Comment: Just in case someone in the future wants to know what fixed the problem.
I was getting a XML error from twilio console debugger and the following fixed the issue:
from flask import Flask, request, Response
return Response(str(response), mimetype="application/xml")

Answer source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68508372/warning-12200-schema-validation-warning-the-provided-xml-does-not-conform-to-t

Comment: Seems like you solved the issue :) Feel free to write the solution as an answer below and mark the question completed.

Comment: oh my bad. I'll do that right! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone in the future wants to know what fixed the problem. I was getting a XML error from twilio console debugger and the following fixed the issue:

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response 

return Response(str(response), mimetype="application/xml")
```

Source: [Warning - 12200 Schema validation warning The provided XML does not conform to the Twilio Markup XML schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68508372/warning-12200-schema-validation-warning-the-provided-xml-does-not-conform-to-t)