# Twilio Chatbot with python not responding for message

Tags: python, twilio, sms, chatbot, messaging

I am trying to create twilio chatbot,

```
from flask import Flask,request
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse
app = Flask(__name__)    
@app.route('/sms',methods=['POST'])
def sms():            
        from_number = request.form['From']
        to_number = request.form['To']
        body = request.form['Body']
        resp = MessagingResponse()
        resp.message("The Robots are coming! Head for the hills!")
        return str(resp)
app.run()
```

My post request is working fine, as I can see 200 code for each post request

[image]

This is my ngrok terminal. As my request is going, my response message is not reflecting in twilio sandbox. Nothing responding in my whatsapp.
When I tried to monitor the error log its showing like this, not sure why this is happening.

```
WARNING - 12200
Schema validation warning
The provided XML does not conform to the Twilio Markup XML schema. Please refer to the specific error and correct the problem. ## Warning - 12200
```

[image]
http://localhost:4040/inspect/http

[image]
I am new to this please someone help me why its not responding with my message.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning - 12200 Schema validation warning The provided XML does not conform to the Twilio Markup XML schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68508372/warning-12200-schema-validation-warning-the-provided-xml-does-not-conform-to-t)

Comment: No, I tried my response replacement with this doesn't helped me. return Response(str(response), mimetype="application/xml")

Comment: Can you try to access the ngrok web interface that runs on localhost:4040 and check what data it returns?

Comment: @IObert I have updated screenshot of localhost:4040. please check my API is triggering sms API and response also 200 code but not responding msg in whatsapp

Comment: @IObert my issue fixed, I just added app.run(debug=True) seems working fine! Thanks for your help